# Update multiple NA columns to 0

Tags: r, dataframe

How to efficiently update multiple columns from NA to 0? Don't want to update all NA to 0. Only certain columns need be updated.

My current solution: Is there a better method?

```
dataframe$col1 = replace(dataframe$col1, is.na(dataframe$col1), 0)

dataframe$col2 = replace(dataframe$col2, is.na(dataframe$col2), 0)

dataframe$col3 = replace(dataframe$col3, is.na(dataframe$col3), 0)
```

Syntax used and this is not working as expected. Meaning, does not replace NA to 0.

```
dataframe = dataframe %>% mutate(across(c('col1', 'col2', 'col3'), ~ replace(., all(is.na(.)), 0)))
```

Sample Data.

> structure(list(`col1` = c(63755.4062, 61131.3242,
> 61131.3242, 192055.25, 191429.9844, 190076.4688), `col2` = c(18.8754,
> 14.6002, 14.6002, 24.0053, 24.4012, 25.3588), `col3` = c(NA,  NA, NA, 45.6442, 43.9821, 47.2581)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

Following worked. Thanks @MATT, and @Karthik.

```
 dataframe = dataframe %>% mutate(across(c('col1', 'col2', 'col3'), ~  ~tidyr::replace_na(., 0)))
```

Comment: In your current solution `col1` is lowercase, and in your syntax that's throwing an error, you capitalized the C in `Col1`. The following should work for you: `dataframe %>% mutate(across(c(col1, col2, col3), ~ replace(., all(is.na(.)), 0)))`

Comment: @Matt, Thanks. It is not throwing syntax errors but it is not replacing NA with 0. Not sure what is the correct syntax to use replace.

Comment: Did you reassign the dataframe? `dataframe <- dataframe %>% mutate(across(c(col1, col2, col3), ~ replace(., all(is.na(.)), 0)))`

Comment: Yes. I did reassign but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data? By using `dput(head(dataframe))` or pasting a sample `data.frame` that is similar to your data?

Comment: @Matt, Added sample data. Thanks for looking into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why Karthik's solution still returns `NA` for your sample data, but using `replace_na` from `tidyr` seems to work:

```
library(tidyr)

dataframe %>% mutate(across(c('col1', 'col2', 'col3'), ~ replace_na(., 0)))
```

Which gives us:

```
       col1    col2    col3
1  63755.41 18.8754  0.0000
2  61131.32 14.6002  0.0000
3  61131.32 14.6002  0.0000
4 192055.25 24.0053 45.6442
5 191429.98 24.4012 43.9821
6 190076.47 25.3588 47.2581
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Will experiment and get back.

Comment: I believe, replace_na is part of tidyr.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
df <- tibble(c1 = round(rnorm(10, 10,1)),
             c2 = NA_real_,
             c3 = round(rnorm(10, 10,1)),
             c4 = NA_real_,
             c5 = round(rnorm(10, 10,1)),
             c6 = NA_real_)
df
# A tibble: 10 x 6
      c1    c2    c3    c4    c5    c6
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1    12    NA    11    NA    11    NA
 2     9    NA    10    NA    10    NA
 3    11    NA    11    NA    10    NA
 4    11    NA     9    NA    10    NA
 5    10    NA     9    NA    10    NA
 6     9    NA    13    NA    12    NA
 7    10    NA    10    NA     9    NA
 8    10    NA    10    NA     9    NA
 9    11    NA    11    NA    10    NA
10    10    NA    10    NA    10    NA
df %>% mutate(across(c3:c6, ~ replace(., all(is.na(.)), 0)))
# A tibble: 10 x 6
      c1    c2    c3    c4    c5    c6
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1    12    NA    11     0    11     0
 2     9    NA    10     0    10     0
 3    11    NA    11     0    10     0
 4    11    NA     9     0    10     0
 5    10    NA     9     0    10     0
 6     9    NA    13     0    12     0
 7    10    NA    10     0     9     0
 8    10    NA    10     0     9     0
 9    11    NA    11     0    10     0
10    10    NA    10     0    10     0
```

Comment: mutate(across(c3:c6, ~ replace(., all(is.na(.)), 0))). Is there a way to specify column names? Columns are not necessarily in order for me to replace.

Comment: Looks like this is feasible across(c(col1, col2, col3))

Comment: @nsivakr, you can use: df %>% mutate(across(c(c3,c4,c5,c6), ~ replace(., all(is.na(.)), 0)))

Comment: Throwing the following error, Input `..1` must be a vector, not a `formula` object. Input `..1` is `~...`.

Comment: @nsivakr, can you check your syntax? It's syntactic error.

Comment: Added the syntax that was used in the original post. However, it is not replacing the NA columns to 0. Let me know, what needs to be changed.

Comment: @nsivakr, don't use quotes. use column names directly: mutate(across(c(col1,col2,col3

Comment: the column names have spaces. Thus, need for quotes are necessary.

Comment: Use ` not '. i.e. use the one above your 'tab' button.

Comment: I'm lost here. use the one above your 'tab' button

Comment: @nsivakr    You need to use ` and not '

Comment: Both single quote and back quotes works. But the key is to use tidyr::replace_na. Not sure why replace did not work.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way IMO would be to subset the columns you want to edit as a new dataframe, edit all NAs in the subset to 0, then overwrite your original df's selected columns.

```
    DFsubset <- DF[,10:12] #whichever columns
    DFsubset[is.na(DFsubset) == T] <- 0
    DF[,10:12] <- DFsubset
```